# How one should prevent changing the state of the object in Java ( with respect to FP)?

Tags: java, functional-programming

Imagine I have method like this:

```
public int doSomething(String value)
{
    this.value = value
    //calculation
    //based on value return the op
    return op;
}
```

This method does change the state of the object. While I was reading the book [FP In Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), author says, in such cases, we need to return the new state along with the new object. Something like this:

```
public List<Integer,AnClass> doSomething(String value)
{
        AnClass obj = new AnClass();
        obj.value = value
        //calculation
        //based on value return the op
        //return List of op,new AnClass 
}
```

The reason being is, `doSomething` is a side-effect method, which does modify the state of an object. Rather, the revised version, does create a new object and doesn't change the `value` of the old object.

With respect to this, I have few questions:

1. Imagine `AnClass` has loads of instance variables, if one should copy all of them into a new object, how should I do that?
2. Is it always good that we shouldn't change the state of an object as author claims? In such cases, we need to take the similar approach, as I have done above?
3. If we keep on creates the java objects, doesn't use loads of heap memory? Does that degrades my speed of the application?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Deep** and **shallow** copy are the buzzwords you are looking for. There are several threads on SO how to properly do it in Java. Which one you use depends on the class structure. Can you guarantee that **every** variable included in you class is immutable? Choose shallow copy if so. If not you have no other choice but to go with the more expensive deep copy.
2. Functional programing as a paradigm can save you a lot of troubles in terms of side effects or parallelization. I would recommend using it if you are expecting future troubles with side effects or are about to fix some. It depends on the use case though, sometimes a little mutability is cleaner and more performant. It is really about you as a programmer knowing the FP paradigm and being able to apply it on appropriate cases. Your approach there does not look very clean to me. I would have a look at shallow copy methods for Java as I pointed out in 1. Then you should be able to do a copy of `AnClass` while applying new `value` through constructor to it. You should not be able to change `obj.value` as you pointed out in your code, it has to be private. Afterwards you can call your `public int doSomething(AnClass copiedImmutableInstance)` method. That said without knowing the whole context of your code.
3. Yes it does, but that really depends on whether you use deep or shallow copy. Latter one should not have such an impact as the former one.

Finally I would say that Java was not designed for functional programing in first place. It surely gets more functional features lately, but you can hardly go pure functional in that language.